# Texture not Assigning to GameObject on Button Click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures

I'm hung up on something that I've not been able to work out and I could really use a fresh set of eyes on it. I'm loading up an array of images, assigning one of them to a texture in LoadGallery.cs. Then in LoadImage I have a button that when clicked runs LoadImg but when I click the button nothing happens. The texture doesn't get assigned to the GameObject. I'm not getting any errors either. The script works fine when it's all within the IEnumerator function, but when I pull it out into a different script I'm getting nothing. What am I getting wrong?

LoadGallery.cs

```
public Texture2D tex;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    StartCoroutine("LoadAllImages");
}

IEnumerator LoadAllImages()
{
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/TATUS/", "*.png");       
    WWW www = new WWW("file://" + filePaths[0]);                                            
    yield return www;                                                                               
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(512,512);                                                         
    www.LoadImageIntoTexture(tex);
}
```

LoadImage.cs

```
void LoadImg() 
{
    GameObject galleryLoader = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GalleryLoader");
    LoadGallery loadGallery = galleryLoader.GetComponent<LoadGallery>();

    Rect rct = new Rect(0, 0, loadGallery.tex.width, loadGallery.tex.height);
    Vector2 pvt = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);

    GameObject screenShotImg = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("screenshot");
    Image img = screenShotImg.GetComponent<Image>();
    img.sprite = Sprite.Create(loadGallery.tex, rct, pvt);
}
```

Comment: whats the problem when it is working with `IEnumerator` ?

Answer (score 0):

I could not see what's wrong with what you are doing. These are common mistakes from my experience:
1. You might have forgotten to assign the function LoadImg to the button.
2. The size of UI object "screenshot" is too small. Try assigning some dummy image to see if it's actually showing something.
3. There could have been some exception when loading gallery. Try to check for www.error. Debug it carefully.

Good luck with your work.